# How do I stop my infinite scroll from continuously calling for more profiles once the collection is empty?

Tags: vue.js

So I have an infinite scroll that loads 4 more profiles each time a user scrolls to the bottom but the problem is it continues to try and do this even once the collections empty which isn't good because it will drive up costs on the amount of reads it does and I'm not sure how to stop it when theres no more profiles left.
Heres my script from vue

```
<script>

import getPremium from "../Composables/getPremium.js";
export default {
  setup() {

    const { Premium, error, load } = getPremium();
    load();

    var lastLoaded = Date.now()
    var timer = null

    // return { Premium, Standard, Basic, error, load, load2 }
    return {lastLoaded, timer, Premium, error, load}
  },
  methods: {
    doQuery() {
      let time = Date.now()
      // if it has not been one second since the last load bail here
      if (this.lastLoaded+1000 > time) {
        return
      }
      // get the current pos + the visible window height
      let currentPos = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight
      // get the document height all up
      let docHeight = document.body.scrollHeight
      // if at the bottom of the page do the query
      if (currentPos >= docHeight) {
        // do the query here 
       // console.log("load")
       // console.log(this.lastLoaded)
        this.load()
        // set the last loaded time
        this.lastLoaded = time
      }

    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // add an event listner for the scroll event
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.doQuery);
    // add a timer function to execute the doQuery function
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.doQuery()
    }, 1000)
  }
}


</script>
```

I've got the set interval because otherwise it loads multiple of the same item before continuing on to the next ones.
Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Would this limiting in the javascript file it gets them from stop the reads?

```
import { projectFirestore } from "../Firebase/Config";
import { ref } from "vue"

const getPremium = () => {
    const Premium = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)
    let lastDoc = null; 

    const load = async () => {
        try {
            let query = projectFirestore.collection('Premium').orderBy('createdAt').limit(12)
            if (lastDoc) {
                query = query.startAfter(lastDoc)
            }

            const res = await query.get()

            if (!res.empty) {
                lastDoc = res.docs[res.docs.length - 1]

                // Add new results to exsiting ones

                Premium.value = [...Premium.value, ...res.docs.map(doc => {
                  //  console.log(doc.data())
                    return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
                })]
            }
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
           // console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { Premium, error, load }
}

export default getPremium
```

Comment: If you own the back-end server, modify the response so it includes a flag that tells the UI whether or not there are more items left in the collection.  If not, modify your UI code so that if it receives less than the expected number of profiles (4 in  your case), it means there are no more and you stop querying.